# How to delete some rows of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to delete some rows of a pandas dataframe but it's not working.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('owid-co2-data.csv')

to_drop = ['Europe' , 'Asia' , 'Africa' , 'North America' , 'South America' ,
           'Central America' , 'Oceania' , 'World' , 'Low-income countries' ,
           'Lower-middle-income countries' , 'Upper-middle-income countries' ,
           'High-income countries']
country = df.drop(to_drop, inplace=True axis=1)
```

Comment: You can't use `drop` since your index is a range by default. You have to target explicitly the column to be used: `out = df[~df['your_col'].isin(to_drop)]`